# How to tap() an iterator?

Tags: rust, functional-programming

What's the Rust equivalent of [tap()](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#tap)?

It calls a function on each item in the iterator like `map()` but instead of passing the value returned by the function, `tap()` returns the original item.

For example, I'd like to call `println!()` in the middle of my stream somehow:

```
foo.into_iter()
  .filter(|x| x == target)
  .tap(|x| println!("{:?}", x)) // <-- what goes here?
  .map(|c| c.result)
```

Correction:

`tap()` calls the closure once on the entire iterator
`inspect()` calls the closure on each item in the iterator

Comment: This question might be better suited for [softwareengineering.se] since it is a general programming question rather than solving an actual problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is on `Iterator` as [`.inspect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect):

```
foo.into_iter()
  .filter(|x| x == target)
  .inspect(|x| println!("{:?}", x))
  .map(|c| c.result)
```

Answer (score 4):

What you described is not `tap`, but `inspect`, as @kmdreko pointed out. A general purpose [tap](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/tap/trait.Tap.html#method.tap) (alongside with a general purpose [pipe](https://docs.rs/tap/1.0.1/tap/pipe/trait.Pipe.html#method.pipe) - generic `map` which signature you could express as `a -> (a -> b) -> b`) is implemented by third-party [tap](https://crates.io/crates/tap) library.